# C# Switch statement scenario

Tags: c#

UPDATED:

Is there a way to accomplish what the code below attempts to do (doesn't pass syntax because case 2 and case 3 can't have duplicate declarations and/or because num can't be 2 and 3 at the same time)?

```
        var num = 0;
        switch (num)
        {
            case 1:
                //do stuff applicable to 1 only;
                break;
            case 2:
                //do stuff applicable to 2 only;
                break;
            case 3:
                //do stuff applicable to 3 only;
                break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
                //do stuff applicable to 2 and 3 only;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: The logic makes no sense. How would you pass in a 2 and 3 in a single int?

Comment: `switch` cannot do what you need. use `if`.

Comment: @AgentFire - even with an `if` it could still not be done. A single int cannot represent 2 values (2 and 3).

Comment: @Igor there is no `and`, but `or`.

Comment: @AgentFire - That part of the if (the or) would still never be hit because 2 or 3 have already been evaluated for earlier in the chain.

Comment: The marked answer is precisely what I was looking for, therefore I don't think this question should have been marked down.

Comment: @ChadMizner I believe the down votes are because people felt that the question was unclear because you seem to want to assign the `text` variable based on `num` being 1, 2, 3 or both 2 and 3.  Something that just had the text as comments or different methods would have been clearer.

Comment: @juharr, fair enough, but it was clear to one guy, :)

Comment: @ChadMizner Maybe, but look at how Eric and I answered the question by not assigning something to `text` but instead we assumed you just have things you want to do and that you represented them with that string assignment which inadvertently made your question confusing.

Comment: thanks @juharr, updated question, better?

Comment: can you all slow down with the down votes??  is my UPDATED question still horrible?   it seemed to spawn a decent amount of useful discussion IMO and obliviously many understood what I meant, if i knew the absolute perfect way, it wouldn't be a question in the first place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not with a single-level `switch` (or a nasty GOTO).  A switch can only execute one case.  A better solution would be a nested `if` (or `switch`) within the 2/3 case:

```
switch (num)
{
    case 1:
        //do stuff applicable to 1 only
        break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
        if(num == 2)
        {
            //do stuff applicable to 2 only
        }
        if(num == 3)
        {
            //do stuff applicable to 3 only
        }
        //do stuff applicable to 2 OR 3
        break;
}
```

Comment: Of course this exact code is the same if you remove the two if statements since the intermediate assignments to `text` don't seem to matter.  This is an artifact from the question that made it unclear in the first place.

Comment: @juharr True - I converted those to comments to get rid if that ambiguity.

Comment: You don't need two if constructs. It could simply be an if-else construct here, given that num can only be 2 or 3.

Answer (score 6):

The question is confusingly posed. I think what you want is to have a case that runs for two, a case that runs for three, and a case that runs for two-or-three.

Just use two switches:

```
    switch (num)
    {
        case 1: One(); break;
        case 2: Two(); break;
        case 3: Three(); break;
    }
    switch (num)
    {
        case 2:
        case 3: TwoOrThree(); break;
    }
```

Or

```
    switch (num)
    {
        case 1: One(); break;
        case 2:
        case 3: 
          switch (num)
          {
            case 2: Two(); break;
            case 3: Three(); break;
          }
          TwoOrThree();
          break;
    }
```

Or duplicate the code:

```
    switch (num)
    {
        case 1: One(); break;
        case 2: Two(); TwoOrThree(); break;
        case 3: Three(); TwoOrThree(); break;
    }
```

I would NOT recommend un-duplicating the code like this:

```
    switch (num)
    {
        case 1: One(); break;
        case 2: Two(); goto twoOrThree; break;
        case 3: Three(); twoOrThree: TwoOrThree(); break;
    }
```

Yuck.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as this...

```
switch (value)
{
    case 1:
        // Do 1 stuff
        break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
        // We can use an if-else construct here given that there's only two possibilities.
        if (value == 2)
        {
            // 2 only stuff here
        }
        else
        {
            // 3 only stuff here
        }

        // Do anything applicable to BOTH here, or above the if construct, depending on your requirements.

        break;
    default:
        // Any other stuff here
        break;
}
```

Or just use an if construct, which is arguably cleaner (switch is really only intended for simple many to one logical mappings)...

```
if (value == 1)
{
    // 1 stuff
}
else if (value == 2 || value == 3)
{
    if (value == 2) {
        // 2 stuff only
    }
    else
    {
        // 3 stuff only
    }

    // 2 or 3 stuff, or above the if construct above, if you require.
}
else
{
    // Anything else here
}
```

Or simply...

```
switch (value)
{
    case 1:
        OneStuff();
        break;
    case 2:
        TwoStuff();
        TwoOrThreeStuff();
        break;
    case 3:
        ThreeStuff();
        TwoOrThreeStuff();
        break;
    default:
        AnythingElse();
}
```

And wrap what you need to do for each of the above in separate methods.

The third method would be my preference here. It's cleaner and easier to debug than using complex mixtures of switch and if.

Comment: I don't like the 3rd method because you are calling the TwoOrThreeStuff() method twice which what I'm trying to avoid in the first place.  I like your first answer which is the same as the answer I marked as the accepted answer and doesn't duplicate any code.

Comment: There's no duplicate code in the third example either. The TwoOrThreeStuff() would be a single method, only called from two locations. Which is actually the right way to do this kind of logic. Certainly the tersest and most maintainable way of doing it.

Comment: my mistake, i should have said calling the same code twice vs. saying duplicate code.  Isn't it better to call it once vs. twice all else being equal?  Your first way seems just as maintainable/readable/etc?  probably splitting hairs at this point?  just trying to learn/get others perspectives, thx!

Comment: You are only calling it once. The value is only going to be 2 OR 3, it can't be both at the same time, so it's only going to get called once in either case.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `if` statements instead

```
var num = 0;
if(num == 1)
{
    // do stuff applicable to 1 only
}
else if(num == 2)
{
    // do stuff applicable to 2 only
}
else if(num == 3)
{
    // do stuff applicable to 3 only
}
if(num == 2 || num == 3)
{
    // do stuff applicable to 2 AND 3
}
```

Or as a `switch` and an `if`

```
switch (num)
{
    case 1: 
        // do stuff applicable to 1 only
        break;
    case 2: 
        // do stuff applicable to 2 only
        break;
    case 3: 
        // do stuff applicable to 3 only
        break;
}
if(num == 2 || num == 3)
{
    // do stuff applicable to 2 AND 3
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [goto case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/13940fs2.aspx) statement and have a unique identifier for combined operations in case 2 and 3. Make sure that that is never hit by any other number:

```
var num = 0;
var text = "";
switch (num)
{
    case 1:
        text = "do stuff applicable to 1 only";
        break;
    case 2:
        text = "do stuff applicable to 2 only";
        goto case 23;
    case 3:
        text = "do stuff applicable to 3 only";
        goto case 23;
    case 23:
        text = "do stuff applicable to 2 AND 3";
        break;
}
```

The use of goto is not recommended in general but it is common to use it in switch-statements and situations like that.

Comment: But what if `num` is 23?

Comment: @juharr That's why I wrote use a unique number. -23 or 23000, anything that would normally not appear.